# USB-C Dock not using both external monitors

Tags: nvidia, thinkpad, 22.10

On Ubuntu 22.10, I have two HDMI monitors.
If I hook one up to the HDMI port and another to the USB-C port through a HDMI -> USB-C Adapter, it works fine.
We can assume it is not a cable or monitor issue from this.
I don't have another computer to try the dock on, but this is the second dock I tried, and the previous dock I used worked fine for dual monitors on another computer, so I think it is an Ubuntu issue.

I want to plug both monitors into a USB-C dock and have both monitors work.

System statistics.

- Ubuntu 22.10
- X11
- Recent Lenovo Thinkpad

```
[~] uname -a                                                                   
Linux chocrates-workstation 5.19.0-43-generic #44-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue May 16 14:03:43 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
[~] lsusb                                                                      
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 06cb:00f9 Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 04f2:b71c Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Integrated RGB Camera
Bus 003 Device 008: ID 0bda:5418 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. BillBoard Device
Bus 003 Device 010: ID 0bda:1100 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. HID Device
Bus 003 Device 016: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 003 Device 015: ID 046d:082c Logitech, Inc. HD Webcam C615
Bus 003 Device 014: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 003 Device 013: ID 29ea:0102 Kinesis Corporation Advantage2 Keyboard
Bus 003 Device 012: ID 1532:0084 Razer USA, Ltd RZ01-0321 Gaming Mouse [DeathAdder V2]
Bus 003 Device 011: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 003 Device 009: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 0bda:5411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5411 Hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 1050:0406 Yubico.com Yubikey 4/5 U2F+CCID
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0b00:5423 INGENICO 4-Port USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 8087:0032 Intel Corp. AX210 Bluetooth
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0bda:0411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 17e9:6011 DisplayLink Plugable UD-ULTC4K
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0b00:0423 INGENICO 4-Port USB 3.0 Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

```
[~] cat /lib/modprobe.d/nvidia-kms.conf                                                                                                                                
# This file was generated by Nvidia-prime
# Set the value to 1 to enable mode setting
options nvidia-drm modeset=1%
```

```
[~] nvidia-smi                                                                                                                                                         
Fri Jun  9 15:47:07 2023       
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 530.41.03              Driver Version: 530.41.03    CUDA Version: 12.1     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                  Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf            Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3080 L...    Off| 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| N/A   52C    P8               14W /  N/A|    749MiB / 16384MiB |      5%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                                         
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                            |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                            GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                             Usage      |
|=======================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      2673      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                          253MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2975      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                         72MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3973      G   gnome-control-center                         14MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      5488      G   ...irefox/2710/usr/lib/firefox/firefox      397MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      7606      G   /usr/bin/nvidia-settings                      3MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      7683      G   .../jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java        3MiB |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

And for good measure, this is the dock [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0779K9DG2/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o01_s01?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0779K9DG2)

Comment: You use a displaylink dock. Have you installed the displaylink drivers?

Comment: Could also be a cabling issue, do you connect your dock with thunderbolt cable? The amazon photo shows that the dock is delivered with a usb-c cable. o.O  
 https://www.avast.com/c-thunderbolt-vs-usb-c#:~:text=Thunderbolt%20and%20USB%2DC%20cables,much%20faster%20than%20USB%2DC.

Answer (score 0):

This device isn’t officially supported for Linux. But what you may try is using two [Plugable DisplayPort to HDMI Passive Adapters](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01GW8DZV4).

This technique seems to work and is documented in a post on [Plugable’s support forum](https://support.plugable.com/t/linux-and-the-ud-ultc4k-triple-display-dock/11526).

You may also run into other issues with the total number of devices you’ll be able to connect and whatnot. So perhaps you would need to find a different docking station or accept this as a work-around.

Comment: Well crap, how do i figure out if it is supported or not and why?  Most all companies don't officially support it but the open source community does

Comment: @Chris It states on manufacturers website that it’s supported for Mac and Windows. It says nothing about Linux. Also, in that link I provided, someone from the manufacturer states that it’s not supported in Linux. Regarding other products, you’ll have to research each individually.

Answer (score 0):

Your dock [reportedly](https://www.amazon.com/ask/questions/Tx2Y5MV71CUSV3O/ref=ask_dp_dpmw_al_hza) works with Linux.(Most displaylink docks actually do, even if the manufacturer does not report so, because they think this will not influence their sales and they have neither the knowledge nor the capacity to provide the related support).

Please note that this is a displaylink dock. It will not work without the displaylink drivers.
Displaylink drivers for Linux can be found [here](https://www.synaptics.com/products/displaylink-graphics/downloads/ubuntu). This is actually mentioned in the product description you have linked to and is true for Linux too.
Do not confuse displaylink with displayport. You will need the displaylink driver for all Video output on this dock.

Even though Displaylink officially only supports the nouveau driver, on my device the driver also works with the proprietary drivers. (It will not work with the intel card)

Install while the dock is unplugged and restart (as indicated in the instructions)

Comment: Thanks you might be on to something.  Installed the displaylink drivers and it didn't automagically work but I can try to debug more

Answer (score -1):

Your NVIDIA Drives seem to be working fine, but I would still suggest that you try

A rollback and install Nvidia 425 drivers,
and Also, make sure that secure boot settings are working fine on your PC. If it is turned on, then make sure to enroll the mok in the secure boot so that the Nvidia kernel can load up along with Ubuntu. That way, it works fine.

More things to consider, dock the docking station after the system starts/ boots up so that all the processes can load up successfully.

run nvidia-sm[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0DGU.png)i again to see if everything is working now fine. now you could try one more thing. There is this app known as nvidia x server settings; which is basically settings for ur graphics card/driver, there check for x server display configurations after docking up the displays to see whether the system detects them or not if no, then we can assume there is an issue with the link; if it shows all the displays then check for all the settings and configuration and edit them accordingly. There is this specific menu in settings named powermizer in that settings window change the power ode /set it to the maximum possible such that it gives out best through output. Try all of these I hope these worked for as they did for mine. the images associated with powermizer is also linked below.

Comment: Thanks I'll give these a try.